# Missing Pantone Process Magenta C?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, print-design, pantone

I can't find Pantone Process Magenta C in illustrator's color books. I can find Process Yellow C, Process Blue C and Process Black C, but the magenta is missing. I have the color books updated.

Does anyone have an answer or direct me to one?

**Edit:**  Let me elaborate on what I'm trying to accomplish. I am doing a project that will be printed in flexography with pantones. As there will be photos to be printed, I will need to choose the spot colours that best match the CMYK colours, so the final result doesn't diverge much to an offset printing.

Comment: Pantone Process Magenta is in the [CMYK Coated Colour book](https://imgur.com/a/SunZAwQ).  Process Magenta isn't a base colour used for spot colour mixes, so you won't find it in the Pantone Solid Coated book. Also note that Process Blue is not the same as Process Cyan used in CMYK printing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @BillyKerr. Let me elaborate on what I'm trying to accomplish. I am doing a project that will be printed in flexography with pantones. As there will be photos to be printed, I will need to choose the spot colours that best match the CMYK colours, so the final result doesn't diverge much to an offset printing.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the help @BillyKerr. All the best.

Comment: I added an answer now, plus a way for you to check the magenta separation.

Comment: I was so sure of your help that I commented before you finished it. lol thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the update describing what you are actually trying to achieve.

You don't need to set a spot colour for this.

You can simply set the colour of the object you want to print as Process Magenta to 0%C 100%M 0%Y 0%K.  It will print as a solid colour.

Example

[image]

You can check this by clicking *Window > Separations Preview*, engage "overprint preview", hide all except magenta, and you will see what the Magenta separation will look like.

[image]